# Simple REST GET request to youtube API return error

Tags: rest, youtube-api

I'm quite new to working with REST API of various services.
I'm trying to search for videos in youtube.

In GCP I enabled Youtube Data API, generated key and set Referrer Restriction.
In Postman (or in browser - same result) I call GET method with the URL (got from API explorer)

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=angular&key=MY_API_KEY
```

and add Referrer field with correct value into the header.

This is the answer from the service:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
                "message": "The referrer ReferreValue does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
                "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=589726014278"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The referrer ReferreValue does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
    }
}
```

Problems:
1. My project id is not 589726014278;
2. Referrer value is OK, of course not against unknown project id.

Question:
How can I make it work? I want to keep it so simple as possible; w/o OAuth anything. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to recreate your Youtube api key and set the refer value to null based on the answer from [this](https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-automatic-plugin/1904470&ref=webyguy/comments?page=86) discussion.

http://valvepress.com/how-to-get-a-youtube-api-key-to-post-from-youtube-to-wordpress/

[image]

Comment: Regeneration of a key helped. I can use the new key even with set referrer now.